# How to set bibliography text colour in beamercolor.sty file

Tags: latex, org-mode, beamer

I have made a beamer theme for my work presentations that adheres to my company's profile, however I am unable to find the code to set the colour of the bibliography text (or normal unbulleted text for that matter).

This means that the bibliography is shown as white text on the white slide. The text is there, but just in white. The same thing happens with unbulletted text on the slides.

(Additional info: I write the presentation in org-mode and compile it to a beamer pdf.)

The colour theme sty file looks like this:

```
\mode<presentation>

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,66,135}
\definecolor{mmconcept}{RGB}{32,66,135}
\definecolor{mmt1}{RGB}{87.75,113.25,165}
\definecolor{mmt2}{RGB}{143.5,160.5,195}

% Settings
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=myblue}

\mode
<all>
```

I have tried various settings but not seem to work.

I can change the normal text colour to a different colour by putting a latex colour tag into the slide but this doesn't work with the bibliography and I want the theme to sort this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an effort troubleshoot I used the MWE supplied by user36296 and the bibliography showed with and without the colour settings.
This lead me to realise that this problem only occurs when I have my notes showing on the second screen.
Not sure if this is bug but the slides show the bibliography correctly when notes are hidden and in white when notes are on the second screen.

This is not a fix but more of a workaround, but it is the best answer for now.

Comment: This bug might explain the symptoms you notice: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337

Comment: Yeah, that seems like it. Will just have to wait for the fix.

Comment: There are a couple of workarounds: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232168/normal-text-is-invisible-when-using-beamer-with-notes-and-xelatex

Answer (score 7):

The colours of the bibliography are controlled by

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=green}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=orange}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=teal}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}

@article{einstein,
    author = {Einstein, A.},
    title = {Die Grundlage der allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie},
    journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    volume = {354},
    number = {7},
    doi = {10.1002/andp.19163540702},
    pages = {769--822},
    year = {1916}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\mode<presentation>

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{32,66,135}
\definecolor{mmconcept}{RGB}{32,66,135}
\definecolor{mmt1}{RGB}{87.75,113.25,165}
\definecolor{mmt2}{RGB}{143.5,160.5,195}

% Settings
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=myblue}


\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{fg=green}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=orange}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=teal}

\mode
<all>


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \nocite{knuth}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but this may be a bug. See my answer,

Comment: In my document, `\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=teal}` changes the color of the journal name, publisher, publisher location, publication date, and pages.